# Django Logout clears session

Tags: python, django, database

I'm using Session object to store anonymous users data.
I'm adding session_id to my DB through model.
It's not clear, why all data connected with session is deleted when i logout from admin panel? So my records to DB just erase after logout from admin panel. What to do, anybody can help?

```
class SomeOne(models.Model):
    added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    client_session = models.ForeignKey(Session, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

SESSION_COOKIE_AGE is big, so it not expires.

Answer (score 0):

See this is what session means session data get clear alway when you close tab or logout so to prevent that you should store the session data in local storage. from there you can recall it to session through user_token  which is stored in local storage.

While thing is:

1)store the data from session to local storage by user_token

2)fetch data when user open port by user_token

3. fetch all stored data from local storage to session